# Creating a list of historical dates starting today - monthly jumps

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am looking to create a set of dates as follows.

For example, if today's date is 12/01/2016.

I need:

```
 A
```

1 Jan 2016

2 Dec 2015

3 Nov 2015

4 Oct 2015

5 Sep 2015

6 August 2015

and so on.

I would appreciate all the help I can get on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: With your date (12/01/2016) you want to retreive the 1th day in the some month, then substract one month and add one day, this loop for 6 time?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got `12 Jan 2016` in cell `A1` you could then use the following formula in cell `A2` and drag down the formula down for as long as needed.

```
=EDATE(A1,-1)
```

This continues to give you the previous date minus 1 month.

You could then format the cell values as `mmmm yyyy` which will give you the date format that you are looking for.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I meant to say I need Jan 2016 in cell A1, instead of 1 Jan 2016 in cell A1

Comment: Hi, I have managed to solve my problem with your solution, thank you for your help! have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

This code will iterate over the cells from A1 to A100, and fill them with the current month and year, and for each cell, it will subtract one month:

```
Sub test()


MyMonth = Date


For i = 1 To 100

    Range("A" & i).Value = MyMonth
    Range("A" & i).NumberFormat = "[$-406]mmmm yyyy;@"
    MyMonth = DateAdd("m", -1, MyMonth)

Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Jan 2016 in A10. Drag the cell A10 upwards. Fill series with months (Auto Fill option). Copy paste this result in other cell with values.